# google chrome extension: popup.html javascript vs jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am playing around with extending google chrome and I have a simple extension running with the following popup.html file:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    alert("hi from popup.html");
</script>

<body>
Hello World
</body>
```

As soon as I add src attribute with the url to the google jquery CDN the 'alert("hi from popup.html");' no longer runs.

My manifest file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
"popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
"tabs","http://*/*","https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Why does adding the jquery source break the popup?

Comment: Usually you just copy the latest `jquery.min.js` into your extension, instead of getting it from a CDN.

Comment: This has nothing to do with chrome or extensions. This is basic Javascript: a `<script>` has either content or a `src`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to break your scripts up into two statements. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hi from popup.html");
</script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that inline scripts are disallowed now with the manifest version 2.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H3-1